# BibTex on TexMaker not working

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I have just installed texmaker on my linux mint OS. Everything seems to work fine, except for the references. I put a document "references.bib" in the same folder as my "main.tex"; however, texmaker doesn't seem to execute bibtex properly. I receive an "undefined reference" error and a question mark shows up in the pdf.

If I navigate to the folder in my terminal and then call:

```
bibtex main
latex main
latex main
```

I receive errors after the first `latex main` but no errors after the second call, and if I then compile again in texmaker it does the referencing correct. However, I have to do this every time I put in a new reference, which is quite annoying. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi and welcome, you have to call LaTeX first, then BibTeX, then LaTeX again (maybe more than once).

Comment: Hi Johannes, thank you for your answer! It works if I call bibtex/latex from the terminal, but I would like to do everything from within texmaker. How can I configure texmaker such that I don't need to switch to the terminal all the time?

Comment: Usually, eerything will work fine. If you call BibTeX from within TeXmaker, do you get any mesages?

Comment: If, in texmaker, I first call latex, then bibtex, then latex twice and then do "quick build" it works. But if I call "quick build" directly it doesn't

Comment: I am not sure what *quick build* does, but the first LaTeX run is essential, even in the terminal. That first run writes down which entries are cited and BibTeX later reads that information. The next LaTeX run will read what BibTeX wrote down.

Comment: In my version of texmaker, i have different options for *Quick build*. The one currently set is just pdflatex and view the pdf. The next choice includes BibTeX and two more runs of LaTeX. But think about it, you won't always have to run BibTeX and this might slow you down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Johannes_B pointed out, when using BibTeX it is essential to maintain a specific order in commands.

The "Quick Build" command in Texmaker is a shortcut to execute a series of commands at once. What specific serie is executed can be configured via Options -> Configure Texmaker -> Quick Build. The default is set to "PdfLaTex + View PDF". Changing this to "PdfLaTex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTex (x2) + View PDF" solves the problem and allows one to compile and view the project in one command.

[edit]
Additional remark by Johannes_B: speed may suffer when changing these defaults, the user may want to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that first you have to latex or pdflatex scroll through the entire document, once or twice, so you can pick up all the bibliographic references that you used, so you tendiras console or part of compilation of Texmaker first call latex, then to bibtex, and finally to latex to generate the reference.